# How to identify dropped observations from R package 'Matching'

Tags: r, matching, nearest-neighbor

I am using Match function in the R package 'Matching'. Below is the code and results of the matching:

```
nn25 <- Match(Y=Y,Tr=Tr,X=X,estimand = "ATT",M=1,exact=NULL,caliper=0.25,replace=TRUE,ties=FALSE,CommonSupport=FALSE)
summary(nn25)

Estimate...  0.057624 
SE.........  0.0062766 
T-stat.....  9.1807 
p.val......  < 2.22e-16 

Original number of observations..............  50082 
Original number of treated obs...............  2996 
Matched number of observations...............  2256 
Matched number of observations  (unweighted).  2256 

Caliper (SDs)........................................   0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 
Number of obs dropped by 'exact' or 'caliper'  740
```

It says there are 740 treatment observations that have been excluded from the analysis due to a lack of insufficient matches within the 0.25 caliper limit. Because this is 25% of the treatment observations, I'd like to know which observations do not have adequate controls on which to match. Is there a way to identify which observations have been dropped from the analysis?

Comment: If you look at the documentation, it says that the matched data sets produced by a call to the `Match` function are returned in a list called `mdata` (so, for you, `nn25$mdata`). Have you taken a look at what's in that list to see if you can answer your question that way?